# undefined is not an object when gapi.client.init() in iOS - Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, google-api, google-api-js-client

I have this piece of code on my ionic app, it works fine on the browser but not in the device. On the device I receive an error "undefined is not an object" when it gets to gapi.client.init

In the index.html, I uploaded

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
```

the code that throws error

```
  gapi.client.init({
        'apiKey': 'api',
        'discoveryDocs': [discoveryUrl],
        'clientId': 'clientId',
        'scope': SCOPE
    }).then(()  => { ;
      console.log("youtube: initialized");
      this.GoogleAuth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
      console.log(this.GoogleAuth);
this.GoogleAuth.isSignedIn.listen(this.updateSigninStatus.bind(this));

      // Handle initial sign-in state. (Determine if user is already signed in.)
      var user = this.GoogleAuth.currentUser.get();
      this.setSigninStatus();
    });
```

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I guess default security settings are preventing cordova from accessing the google api.js file and thus the `gapi` global object is undefined. you may try to add something like `<access origin="*"/>` to config.xml

another reason for "undefined is not an object" may be that api.js is loaded, but it takes some time while the global `gapi` object is accessible. I use following code

```
        var checkGapiInterval = setInterval(function(){
            if(typeof(gapi) == 'undefined'){
                console.log('gApi is undefined, will try later')
            } else if(typeof(gapi.client) == 'undefined'){
                console.log('gApi.client is undefined, will try later')
            } else {
                clearInterval(checkGapiInterval);
                gapi.client.load(that.API_NAME, that.API_VERSION, function(){
                    resolve();
                }, that.GAPI_ENDPOINT)
            }
        }, 1000)
```